# Безличны ли предложения? Синтаксический разбор

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Являются ли безличными (и если да, то какого типа) следующие предложения?

> 1. Мне хочется попасть в деревню.
> 2. Мне хочется в деревню.
> 3. Мне надо в деревню.
> 4. Вам удавалось не мешать друг другу?
> 5. Спится мне хорошо.

Вроде бы в 1 и 4 есть подлежащие: 'не мешать' и 'попасть', поэтому 1 и 4 личные, правильно?

Во 2 опущен инфинитив, и оно становится безличным, а точнее неопределенно-личным (какой-то глагол, а какой — не определено), верно?

В 5 'спится' — это подлежащее, хорошо — сказуемое. Почему нет? Какого типа это предложение?

В 3 'Надо' — это сказуемое, выраженное служебным словом, или что? Какого типа это предложение?

Comment: Все предложения безличные.